# Regex to extract multiple matching string

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract HostName and Email address from text file using regex. These fields are optional. It is possible that in some cases only one field is available.

For example: if email address is not available is should extract only hostname and vice versa.

I got nearly working regex. Just not working for single case. see the regex in below link.

> `regex: ^.*(MAIL:(?<EMAIL>.*))(HOST:(?<HOSTNAME>.*))?`

https://regex101.com/r/SDOcIR/1

Note: I am not looking this for specific language.

Thanks

Comment: please, post the strings that you are working on and avoid external links

Comment: Maybe `MAIL:(?<EMAIL>.*)|HOST:(?<HOSTNAME>.*)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/02OfQL/2))?

Comment: I just updated the link with that! https://regex101.com/r/SDOcIR/2

Comment: Guys it fixed for 2nd line which was not working but broke all others. Now email field include both host and mail address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Regex: `(?:MAIL:(?<EMAIL>[^ ]+))|(?:HOST:(?<HOSTNAME>.*))`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SDOcIR/3)